# Add js file in two colums layout

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, layout-update, head

I'm trying to add a sript for sidebar only where the sidabar appear.
In my local.xml I added:

```
<page_two_columns_left>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/sidebar.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left>
<page_two_columns_right>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/sidebar.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_right>
<page_three_columns>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/sidebar.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_three_columns>
```

but it does not work.
It works in default handler

```
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/sidebar.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

but in this case it is loaded in 1 column layout and give me a javascript error

how to add the script only where is needed?

Comment: Please add your code in page.xml file instead  of local.xml

Comment: @AjayPatel I tried but it does not work either

Comment: you need to fix only for the 2-column right?

Comment: @AjayPatel no, I need all pages but 1-column, so for the 3-colums too

Comment: can you try ans??

Comment: page_{...} are not handler

Comment: @MineshPatel so, is there another way?

Comment: i don't think it is possible from xml. easy way  just add in template/page/2columns-left.phtml

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code in head.phtml file:

```
<?php 
   $root = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
   if ($root) {
      $rootTpl = $root->getTemplate(); 
      if( $rootTpl == "page/2columns-left.phtml"){
      echo "<script src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl()?>default/js/sidebar.js'  </script>";     
       }  
   }  
?>
```

Comment: share your absolute path for js file.

Comment: \skin\frontend\MYTEMPLATE\default\js\sidebar.js

Comment: \skin\frontend\yourtheme\default\js\sidebar.js not template

Comment: can you tell me what is problem with updated ans?

Comment: hey. maitri.infosys this is my skype id add me so i can check on your screen

Comment: Why you guys creating it complicated ? just add in template/page/2columns-left.phtml //2columns-right.phtml

Comment: because @krybbio need to remove only from 1column. its also need to 2 and 3 columns.  so its better compare to add your code in both file.

Comment: As much as possible, please don't touch `page.xml` inside the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<page_two_columns_left>
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/sidebar.js</name></action>
</block>
</page_two_columns_left>
```

I don't think the `head` reference exists within this layout.
You should also do this in your `local.xml` and don't edit `page.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
<page_two_columns_left>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action> <!-- adds a js referencing to the /js directory -->
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet></action> <!-- adds CSS looking at the skin/ directories ( in reverse order: base/default, default/default, default/yourtheme, yourpackage/yourtheme -->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom_script.js</name><params/></action> <!-- adds a js at the skin/ directories in the same manner as the above addCss directive -->
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left >
```

It is best to modify `local.xml` instead found inside `app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/` if you have a custom skin to work with.

Copy is  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794357/magento-how-to-add-js-or-css-file-in-custom-2column-left-page-using-page-xml-fi).